# UNION statement not working, forced to use JOIN (Performance dominance by either?)

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have a two identical tables from different servers. as a short fix (to help handle a longer fix since we are dealing with VERY legacy Infrastructure) to identifying duplicate PK's, we've decided to have the 1st phase be gathering a list of records whose Primary Key exists in the other database whose table is identical. Even though they would have the same PK's, they would still have different data in the rest of the tuple (or record) such as first name, last name, etc..

I am trying to use this UNION statement since they are both identical tables, but keep getting errors as to "Unknown columns in the 'Where' clause"

```
SELECT T.`hospitalno` AS HospitalnoMain, T.`dateencoded` AS DateEncodedMain,
    T.`firstname` AS FirstNameMain, T.`lastname` AS LastNameMain
FROM registration.`patmaster` T
UNION
SELECT P.`hospitalno` AS HospitalnoAux, P.`dateencoded` AS DateEncodedAux,
    P.`firstname` AS FirstNameAux, P.`lastname` AS LastNameAux
FROM registration.`patmaster` P
WHERE T.`LastNameMain` <> P.`LastNameAux` AND T.`FirstNameMain` <> P.`FirstNameAux`
LIMIT 100
```

So I've settled for this statement that is pulling the correct data (at least through all the adjustments to records to test the query, it is correct).

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT T.`hospitalno` AS HospitalnoMain, T.`dateencoded` AS DateEncodedMain,
        T.`firstname` AS FirstNameMain, T.`lastname` AS LastNameMain
    FROM registration.`patmaster` t
) AS G
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT P.`hospitalno` AS HospitalnoAux, P.`dateencoded` AS DateEncodedAux,
        P.`firstname` AS FirstNameAux, P.`lastname` AS LastNameAux
    FROM registration.`patmaster` p
) H
    ON G.HospitalnoMain = H.HospitalnoAux
WHERE G.`LastNameMain` <> H.`LastNameAux` AND G.`FirstNameMain` <> H.`FirstNameAux`
LIMIT 100
```

--
please excuse the manual entry format.

My question is, which is better performance-wise since it will be pulling large amounts of data through BOTH tables. and if it is UNION, what is wrong with my UNION statement since I've tried variations to the SELECT statement that keep giving me the same "unknown column..." error. Thank you in advance

EDIT
also, if anyone knows how to use SQL in "Code" i would appreciate it. It does not seem to work here as

Comment: I think you misunderstood `UNION`'s usage

Comment: I believe your UNION is failing because of your WHERE clause. For it to work, each query should stand on its own and return the same column names (I believe in the same order but I'm not positive about that). Think of the engine as 'stacking' one result set on top of the other. Your where clause is failing because it's looking for a table T in the second query but there is no table T in the second query.  Once you get it to work, I believe you'll want to use a UNION ALL rather than just a UNION (without the ALL, the duplicate rows you're trying to find will each be combined into a single row)

Comment: These queries return different things. You haven't told us what rows either query is supposed to return. And you haven't told us what (possibly third) query's result is actually what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Your `left join` is fine . . . assuming it does what you want.  However, don't use subqueries in the `from` clause if they are not needed.  MySQL materializes such subqueries, incurring additional overhead.

```
SELECT T.`hospitalno` AS HospitalnoMain, T.`dateencoded` AS DateEncodedMain, 
       P.`hospitalno` AS HospitalnoAux, P.`dateencoded` AS DateEncodedAux, P.`firstname` AS FirstNameAux, P.`lastname` AS LastNameAux
FROM registration.`patmaster` t INNER JOIN
     registration.`patmaster` p
  ON p.hospitalno = t.hospitalno
WHERE t.`LastNameMain` <> p.`LastName` AND t.`FirstNameMain` <> p.`FirstName`
LIMIT 100;
```

Note:  The `where` clause turns the outer join into an inner join anyway, so there is reason to make it an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this query (like the original) will pull duplicate copies of the rows, one row with the "Main" and "Aux" values reversed.

In the more general case, where there's a possibility that firstname or lastname could be NULL, we can use a null-safe comparison `<=>` (spaceship) operator so the comparison will will return only TRUE or FALSE, and not return a NULL.

```
SELECT t.`hospitalno`    AS HospitalnoMain
     , t.`dateencoded`   AS DateEncodedMain
     , t.`firstname`     AS FirstNameMain
     , t.`lastname`      AS LastNameMain 
     , p.`hospitalno`    AS HospitalnoAux
     , p.`dateencoded`   AS DateEncodedAux
     , p.`firstname`     AS FirstNameAux
     , p.`lastname`      AS LastNameAux
 FROM registration.`patmaster` t
 LEFT
 JOIN registration.`patmaster` p
   ON p.hospitalno = t.hospitalno
      AND NOT ( t.firstname <=> p.firstname )
      AND NOT ( t.lastname  <=> p.lastname  )
```